# Wordpress published content (post) is not visible until open again and update it

Tags: wordpress

I have imported custom post type name "listing" through excel file as published now the post not showing on category and blog or archive page but can be viewed single by opening from wordpress backend
I do not want to reopen all post and update it one by one because these are 2944 no. of posts
any help ?

Comment: what is the status of the posts?

Comment: post status is published and visibility is public

Comment: are you calling that particular post type in the pages?

Comment: I am calling them by custom taxonomy template